# Reg. Background fit image with the text using HTML&CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a image with the size of 320 * 436 and some particular text data. I need to implement the webpage with the background image as stretch and fit to the screen and the text over the screen. Please help me to implement this using HTML and CSS. Below I have mentioned the code that I have tried. But it does not works:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="background.png">
    <p>Data</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: where is the backgounrd image ? you are using an image ... and where is the content ?

Comment: Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You are expected to have done your research before posting a question. A simple Google search for what you want will give you lots or results telling you exactly what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting your image as a CSS background image with background size set to cover.

```
body {
  background-image: url(background.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

This will stretch your image to cover the screen, you can then position your text over it.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {

          background: url(background.png);
          background-repeat: no-repeat;
          -webkit-background-size: cover;
          -moz-background-size: cover;
          -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center center fixed;

    }
```